# What replaces DatabaseMetaData in Hibernate 5?

Tags: database, metadata, hibernate-5.x

In Hibernate 4, there was an `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata` class that provided information about the underlying database.

I have some logic based on this, namely using the `DatabaseMetadata` class to provide some information about a table by returning a `TableMetadata` instance, like this:

```
databaseMetadata = new DatabaseMetadata(connection, dialect, null);
TableMetadata tableMetadata = databaseMetadata.getTableMetadata(TABLE_NAME, "", "", false);
if (tableMetadata == null) {
    tableMetadata = databaseMetadata.getTableMetadata(TABLE_NAME, databaseUsername, "", false);
}
```

However, in Hibernate 5, the `DatabaseMetadata` class is gone. What replaces it? Is there another way to obtain a `TableMetadata` instance?

Comment: I just answered this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694436/migrating-to-hibernate-5-x)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating to Hibernate 5.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694436/migrating-to-hibernate-5-x)