# Migrating to Hibernate 5.x

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.1, hibernate-5.x

I am migrating my application to Hibernate 5 from Hibernate 3. We are using `DatabaseMetadata` class to get `TableMetadata`. Hence using `TableMetadata` object to get DB table column information like column size, type..etc. It seems in Hibernate 5 `DatabaseMetadata` class got deprecated (removed!). Are there any alternatives for `DatabaseMetadata` class in Hibernate 5? Or else how to get `TableMetadata` in Hibernate 5 env?

Comment: Deprecated classes and methods are listed here with their alternatives. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/deprecated-list.html

Comment: Alan, It's removed from 5.x. It's available in 4.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It got removed in 5.0 as we moved to a new approach to schema tooling.  DatabaseMetadata represented the existing catalog/schema information from the underlying database.  In 5.0 that role is served by `org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.DatabaseInformation`.  That (and DatabaseMetadata before it) are really supported just for use in schema validation and schema migration (update) code.  It is passed into those calls.  I assume you are using this is a different way.  That is not necessarily supported, but if you want to continue that anyway, you'd just instantiate a `org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl` instance.

Comment: Hi @Sydubabu, I'm desperately trying to integrate my DB scripts into Hibernate's schema update. Could you please give an example of how to use org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.DatabaseInformation? I'm coming from Hibernate 3.2.3-ga. Moving to 5.1.0-Final